# How do you find, which project a run URL is from?

Tags: command-line-interface, google-cloud-run

I've inherited a large GCP Organization and we recently ran our first pentest. The results have included a number of URLs. Instead of manually checking each bucket, and run URL against the whole environment. Is there a command I can use in CLI to find the project linked to the URL?

I know that you can do the opposite entering a project and then:

```
gcloud run services list --platform managed
```

But I can't find a way to do the reverse.

Comment: My first thought would be write a script that lists the projects in your GCP organization and then for each project, list the Cloud Run instances and their exposed URLs.  I'm not aware of any mechanism to reverse an exposed URL back to the service (or project).

Comment: @Kolban that's a great idea, wish I had the skillset to do I have a teammate who's a developer and I'll try to get some advice from him on how to do that.

Comment: This would be straightforward (for Cloud Run) as long as `gcloud run` uses the Run v2 because (unlike v1), v2 isn't region-specific. I don't have any Cloud Run services deployed but I'll add a tentative answer.

Answer (score 1):

The scripts enumerate:

1. `--platform=managed` Cloud Run services
2. Cloud Storage buckets

...in Projects accessible to the authenticated user.

<strike>Hmmm.... I don't have any Cloud Run services deployed to test this, so the following is:</strike>

- from memory
- with caveats

###### Cloud Run

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# PROJECTS for which the account has access!
# Extract the Project IDs
PROJECTS=$(\
  gcloud projects list \
  --format="value(projectId)")

# Iterate over the PROJECTS
printf "%s,%s\n" "project_id" "cloud_run_service_name"
for PROJECT in ${PROJECTS}
do
  # Only proceed if Cloud Run is enabled in PROJECT
  ENABLED="$(\
    gcloud services list \
    --project=${PROJECT} \
    --filter=config.name=run.googleapis.com \
    --format='value(state)')"
  if [ "${ENABLED}" = "ENABLED" ]
  then
    # (Cloud Run) SERVICES across all regions
    SERVICES=$(\
      gcloud beta run services list \
      --platform=managed \
      --project=${PROJECT} \
      --format="csv[no-heading](metadata.name,status.address.url)")
    for SERVICE in ${SERVICES}
    do
      # Pseudo-CSV so that the results can be piped to a file
      # Imported into a spreddie
      printf "%s,%s\n" ${PROJECT} ${SERVICE}
    done
  fi
done
```

###### Cloud Storage

Uses the new (!?) `gcloud storage` alternative to `gsutil`.

Same as above replacing `gcloud beta run services list` with `gcloud storage buckets list`:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# PROJECTS for which the account has access!
# Extract the Project IDs
PROJECTS=$(\
  gcloud projects list \
  --format="value(projectId)")

# Iterate over the PROJECTS
printf "%s,%s\n" "project_id" "cloud_storage_bucket_name"
for PROJECT in ${PROJECTS}
do
  # Only proceed if Cloud Storage is enabled in PROJECT
  ENABLED="$(\
    gcloud services list \
    --project=${PROJECT} \
    --filter=config.name=storage.googleapis.com \
    --format='value(state)')"
  if [ "${ENABLED}" = "ENABLED" ]
  then
    # (Cloud Storage) BUCKETS across all regions
    BUCKETS=$(\
      gcloud storage buckets list \
      --project=${PROJECT} \
      --format="csv[no-heading](name)")
    for BUCKET in ${BUCKETS}
    do
      # Pseudo-CSV so that the results can be piped to a file
      # Imported into a spreddie
      printf "%s,%s\n" ${PROJECT} ${BUCKET}
    done
  fi
done
```

###### Caveats

- <strike>Doesn't enumerate buckets but the process is similar</strike>
- Doesn't enumerate (non-`managed`) Anthos-based services but ...